# Html/Css resize and crop as browser size changes

Tags: html, css, image, resize, window

I'm doing a project recently and thanks to a friendly tutorial, I managed to find the following code.

**CSS**

```
html { 
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

This code resizes the background image so that the image will fill up the entire screen while maintaining the correct ratio, and it does it while cropping the image if a part of the image is larger than the screen.

The problem I have is that I need to put images on the webpage that "follows" the background. (covers the same area on the background as browser resizes, always same ratio...etc) But of all the methods I've tried, none of them works, and I am wondering if this if possible.

Or in other words, is it possible to achieve the same effect not by making the image a background?

Comment: I think you will need some js for that. Possibly a plugin like this http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: I really cannot follow what's being asked here.

Comment: would you pleas describe your problem more ?

Comment: What I mean is basically, make the image behave like the background using the CSS above.

Answer (score 2):

Use "background-size: cover".

```
.sizedbkgrd {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
  background-image: url(http://i3.photobucket.com/albums/y89/Aden93/dance-party.jpeg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

Create a div with that class.

```
<div class="sizedbkgrd"></div>
```

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/alforno/gXdRf/