# Image cropping depending on current window width

Tags: jquery, css, html, mobile, zurb-foundation

I'm working on a page that contains a large picture (2560 x 1890) on the frontpage. 
This large picture needs to be cropped to the middle depending on the width of the browser.

Example: [Website](http://www.puresang.nl)

When I look at that site the image its "left" offset is recalculated depending on the window width of the browser window, this way the guy in the middle is always visible.

My HTML:

```
<div class="page-background starter">
    <img src="./img/backgrounds/start.png" alt="index-background"/>
</div>
```

How can I correctly calculate the image left offset?

I'm working with Zurb's Foundation 5.4.0

Thanks for the help in advance!

Kind regards
~Dragon54

Comment: Why not just give a width of 100% then the image will scale

Comment: @mplungjan It needs to crop. Depending on the size of the window.

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16741363/html-css-resize-and-crop-as-browser-size-changes

Comment: Sounds like you are better off setting this as a background image using `background-size: cover`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve the centering and cropping by having two wrappers around the image.

HTML:

```
<div class="crop-wrapper">
    <div class="wide-wrapper">
        <img src="image.jpg"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.crop-wrapper{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width:100%;
}
.wide-wrapper {
    left: -200%;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 500%;
}
```

The `.crop-wrapper` acts like a viewport, showing only as much as the browser window allows. The `.wide-wrapper` is just a really wide `<div>` that allows you to center content that's wider than the containers.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y1tyc2uc/).

Answer (score 0):

**TRY THIS**

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="page-background starter">
        <img src="./img/backgrounds/start.png" alt="index-background"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**STYLE**

```
.holder{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.page-background img{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1024px;
    height: auto;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rzf8yL54/)**